# Right way of testing for Exceptions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, nunit, domain-driven-design

I do TDD on a project with 80% simple logic and 20% complex logic. I find myself testing a lot if certaing methods throws an error and wonder about the right way to do it. I use NUnit and JustMock.

I have two ways of doing this. Using the ExpectedException attribute, and spesifying the type. Or writing as below. The pro with writing as below is that I can also assert the exception.message (if i have made a custom one), and if the test fail i get the exception.message shown too. But I wanted to check with others how you do it. So to sum up:

1. Is it normal to have a lot of testing for exceptions like this?
2. Is this the right way to do it:

> Just to explain: A supplier offers certain contracts, a Department accepts one contract but can not have more than one contract with the same supplier (but of cource can have different contracts with different suppliers)

```
    [Test]
    public void Accepting_more_than_one_contract_from_supplier_throws_exception()
    {
        //Arrange
        var department = new Department(Guid.NewGuid(), "1234");
        var supplier = Mock.Create<Supplier>();
        var contract1 = Mock.Create<DeliveryContract>();
        var contract2 = Mock.Create<DeliveryContract>();
        var id = Guid.NewGuid();
        supplier.Arrange(x => x.Id).Returns(id);
        contract1.Arrange(x => x.Supplier).Returns(supplier);
        contract2.Arrange(x => x.Supplier).Returns(supplier);

        //Act
        department.AcceptContract(contract1);

        //Assert
        try
        {
            department.AcceptContract(contract2);
            Assert.Fail("Duplicate contract with supplier did not throw an exception");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {   
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(ArgumentException),ex.GetType(),ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Assert.Throws](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=assertThrows&r=2.5) method:

```
Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => department.AcceptContract(contract2));
```

or

```
Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => department.AcceptContract(contract2), "some message");
```

Comment: Is this a better way to do it than the above?

Comment: Yes, it's defined in NUnit. Don't you think it's better than the try-catch block?

Comment: yeah, i do think so, but so is the ExceptionAttribute ;) But I do think the try/catch block does show very much of the intensions of the test, and how it is supposed to work. In addition the ability to assert the exception message, which is even more unique. Have had some problems with asserting the wrong argumentexception i.e. if I check for an empty string in another field and that throws an ArgumentException and the test passes on the wrong terms.

Comment: Yeah, ExceptedException is an alternative. It's a matter of choice I guess.

Answer (score 2):

As @Ufuk said. Use `Assert.Throws<T>` where T is an exception type.

If you also want to check the exception message use one of this:

```
T Assert.Throws<T>( TestDelegate code, string message );
T Assert.Throws<T>( TestDelegate code, string message, 
        params object[] parms);
```

By the way the data you created for tests shouldn't be mocks but stubs.
By stubs I mean objects which only contains data for tests, in your case you provide behaviour  for objects - not data.

I'd recommend you use of NBuilder [code.google.com/p/nbuilder/](http://code.google.com/p/nbuilder/). You can create clear stubs by it. It also have great flexibility of creating objects, they can be create randomly or exactly prepared for your test case.

The usage in your case:

```
var supplierStub = Builder<Supplier>
                .With(supplier => supplier.Id = id)
                .Build();

var contractsStub = Builder<DeliveryContract>.CreateListOfSize(2)
                .All()
                    .With(contract => contract.Supplier = supplierStub)
                .Build();
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice on NBuilder. Only one question, do you find yourself doing a lot of these kind of tests or is it bad code to test for exceptions like this?

Comment: It depends on class logic flow. In your example throwing exception isn't obvious and it's part of class logic, so it's reasonable to test it. Remember that tests could be good documentation of your code.

I'm testing code for exceptions mostly when I throw them directly in code (by throw) or when program could throw an exception in some cases. 

For me good example is testing servis responsible for reading .xml file f.e. by LinqToXml. Good case to test is how the service will behave if one node is missing.